# How to save Bandwidth used on Firefox

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions, bandwidth

My ISP is charging me per GB for download. I need some solution to save Web pages on firefox and when I open page again, FF load it from cache offline.

Comment: Per GB on the GB?

Comment: Disable automatic image downloading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Squid proxy.  Set that up on a computer and configure firefox to use it.  It will cache as much as you allow it based on hard drive usage.

Comment: is there exist any good addons

Comment: @Wasim addons for what specifically?

Comment: that can cache contents and load content offline, specially images

Comment: @Wasim It should cache everything even downloads and images.  From the website "Squid is a fully-featured HTTP/1.0 proxy which is almost (but not quite - we're getting there!) a fully-featured HTTP/1.1 proxy."

Comment: it was harder to configure, took my 2 hours. I suggest not to change the default directory to c:\squid. it will take your time. and you can not use path with space like d:\program file\squid. it will not accept space

Comment: @Wasim did you try quoting the path "d:\program file\squid"?  Without quotes programs will not accept spaces.

Comment: i have, but it failed

Comment: can any one of explain another squid issue. How to cache https web content using squid. I found squid 2.7 is not caching websites with https

Comment: @WasimA. It can't cache https, not without performing a mitm attack to the client (yourself), in this "https era" your best bet is maxing out Firefox's own cache size.

Answer (score 3):

- use "text mode" browsing

  - force firefox into "text mode" with the addon [html content blocker](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/html-content-blocker/)
  - use a text browser that will only download HTML.
    i like the ["links" text browser](http://links.twibright.com/) cos it can show images in "graphics mode" = `links -g`
- use an "image compressor" proxy to convert images to low quality.
  for example: firefox-addon [bandwidth hero](https://github.com/ayastreb/bandwidth-hero/)
  and compressor-proxy [bandwidth hero proxy](https://github.com/ayastreb/bandwidth-hero-proxy/)

  - for low security needs, [deploy a free proxy](https://heroku.com/deploy?template=https://github.com/ayastreb/bandwidth-hero-proxy) at heroku.com
  - for high security needs, set up your own "compressor proxy" on an unlimited connection
- use a "data compressor" proxy to compress all uncrypted data:
  HTML, images, [audio?], [video?]. crypted data [over HTTPS] is not compressed.
  to also compress crypted data, run a proxy on your own hardware on an unlimited connection.
  then you also have full control over the compression algorithm.
  for example, you could use [html2text](https://github.com/aaronsw/html2text) to convert HTML to Markdown,
  to get "plain text" with minimal formatting and hyperlinks.
  in numbers: [this page](https://superuser.com/questions/636489/how-to-save-bandwidth-used-on-firefox) is compressed from 140 KByte to 30 KByte = 80% decrease.

  - [How do I use the Google data compression proxy on Firefox?](https://superuser.com/questions/945924/how-do-i-use-the-google-data-compression-proxy-on-firefox)
  - [mozilla janus](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Mobile/Janus) data proxy
  - [data compression](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/) theory for google chrome
  - [google data compression proxy](https://code.google.com/archive/p/datacompressionproxy/)
- use an adblocker addon like [uBlock Origin](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/ublock-origin/)
- request "light" versions of websites. the implementation is server dependent.

  - with the addon [user-agent switcher](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/uaswitcher/) to send a custom `user-agent` header, for example "mobile / android phone"
  - with the addon [save-data: on](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/save-data/) to send the `save-data: on` header. this seems to be ignored by most websites
- avoid "web interfaces" and use "fat clients" aka "apps"
- to read/write emails, use a lightweight IMAP/Sendmail client like [balsa](https://pawsa.fedorapeople.org/balsa/) / [claws](https://www.claws-mail.org/) / [sylpheed](http://sylpheed.sraoss.jp/en/)
- for chatting, use IRC / XMPP
- to play media streams, use [youtube-viewer](https://github.com/trizen/youtube-viewer) / [minitube](https://flavio.tordini.org/minitube) / [auryo](https://auryo.com/)

Comment: That doesn't address the question about Firefox and cache.

Answer (score 2):

Besides having static files cached, here are a few things you can do to conserve bandwidth:

- [Try mobile version of popular websites](http://mvark.blogspot.in/2012/04/low-bandwidth-try-mobile-version-of.html) - they are lighter than
  pages made for desktop browsers
- [Block unwanted images/image ads
  originating from a specific domain](http://mvark.blogspot.in/2011/09/how-to-block-imagesimage-ads.html) - Flash and image ads suck up
  a lot of bandwidth. You can also [block them via the HOSTS file](http://mvark.blogspot.in/2007/02/how-to-block-iframe-based-ads.html)
  if you're using Windows.
- [Read proxied web pages with Google
  Mobilizer](http://mvark.blogspot.in/2010/10/read-proxied-mobile-friendly-web-pages.html)